# What happened after sudo -s

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I am new in shell.

I'am writing a very basic script:

```
#!/bin/bash
example()
{

    echo "Code that don't need sudo."
    sudo -s 
    echo "Code that need sudo"
 }

example
```

After running this script i expect :

1. prompt `Code that don't need sudo.`
2. shell ask me password
3. if the password is OK prompt `Code that need sudo.`

But after typing the good password the prompt `Code that need sudo.` does not appear why and how to fix it ?

Comment: Related: [Why can't we execute a list of commands as different user without sudo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86778)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `sudo -s` starts a root shell, and that's where you find yourself after entering the password. If you then exit the shell, you will see the `Code that need sudo`:

```
$ foo.sh
Code that don't need sudo.
[sudo] password for terdon: 
[root@tpad terdon]# exit
Code that need sudo
```

In general, in all scripts, when you tell it to run a command, the script will only continue executing after the command has finished. So, when your script launched `sudo -s`, it waited for that to finish before continuing. That's why the text was printed after I ran `exit` (or pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

`-s` without a command runs an interactive shell, so you would no longer be in the same shell as the script.

See `man sudo` for details.

This should work though:

```
#!/bin/bash
example()
{

    echo "Code that don't need sudo."
    sudo -s echo "Code that need sudo"
 }

example
```

Comment: Note that there's hardly ever a good reason to use `sudo -s some command` instead of `sudo some command`. With `sudo -s`, `sudo` tries to quote the arguments properly to construct a shell command line that will eventually cause the shell to call `some` with `some` and `command` as argument, but it can't do that properly and even with sh or bash, does it wrong in a few corner cases (can even be tricked to run commands that were not intended).